# How to load dependencies before running npm scripts?

Tags: node.js, build, npm

I'd like to use `npm` for a simple build (inspired by [this article](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)).  I have a single, one-line `script` in my `package.json` that depends on a node module ([`markdown-pdf`](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf)) via require (not as a binary.)

My test setup is a project directory containing a single `package.json` file and recent versions of `npm` and `node`:

```
$ echo "npm: $(npm -v), node: $(node -v)"
npm: 1.4.28, node: v0.10.35
$ ls -a
./            ../           package.json
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "mytest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "markdown-pdf": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node -e \"require('markdown-pdf');\""
  }
}
```

`npm test` fails because the required module is not installed before the `test` script is run:

```
$ npm test

> mytest@0.0.1 test /Users/me/mytest
> node -e "require('markdown-pdf');"


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'markdown-pdf'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at evalScript (node.js:559:25)
    at startup (node.js:80:7)
    at node.js:929:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Is it possible to cause dependencies to be available to JavaScript scripts in a single `package.json` file?

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a CI server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not the way npm was meant to be used, but this should work

```
{
  "name": "mytest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "markdown-pdf": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "node -e \"require('markdown-pdf');\""
  }
}
```

Running `npm test` automatically runs `pretest` first. [Source](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although if you have to run `npm install` before each test you're probably doing something wrong. If this package is being cloned via git rather than installed via NPM it's possible to setup a `git post-checkout hook` which runs immediately following `git clone`. Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Answer (score 1):

Not automagically, no. You'd have to do a `npm install .` first to install the modules in `devDependencies` unless you bundle the `devDependencies` module(s) with your module.

Answer (score 1):

It's may be an abuse of how `npm` is meant to be used, but this `package.json` does it:

```
{
  "name": "mytest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "markdown-pdf": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm install && node -e \"require('markdown-pdf');\""
  }
}
```

Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Eww, `abuse of how npm is meant to be used` is right.